# init float array incrementing index value every x times with Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

What would be the most effective way to initialize a float array of size n incrementing it every x indices using linq

for instance if array increment is 5 starting on 10 and increment size is 5 array would look like

`float[] x =  {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25}`

Comment: How does it stops in 25? what's the logic?

Comment: A `for` loop would probably be both easier to write and easier to understand, given that it's designed specifically to do what you described in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can argue what is the "best" way. Bit the way how i would do it. At first i would create a helper method that helps you to generate Enumerables.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> Unfold<T>(T seed, Func<T, T> accumulator) {
    var nextValue = seed;
    while ( true ) {
        yield return nextValue;
        nextValue = accumulator(nextValue);
    }
}
```

This is a general helper function. For example with

```
Unfold(1, x => x*2)
```

it creates you a new IEnumerable where every new number is the double of the previous number. You should use the .Take() or .TakeWhile() methods to limit the amount of generated numbers. If you for example just want the first 10 numbers with power of two

```
Unfold(1, x => x*2).Take(10).ToList()
```

You get a List with `[1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512]`

Something like Unfold() is in general helpfull to create arbitary Enumerables.

Now to create your list. You wanted to create a list that always add 5. and then every number gets repeated 5 times, and you want reapeat that 4 times. So your first step is

```
Unfold(10, x => x+5).Take(4)
```

It will create you an IEnumerable that contains `[10, 15, 20, 25]`. Now the next step is to repeat every number 5 times.

You can do this with `Enumerable.Repeat()`. The logic would be.

1. Go through your list
2. Create a new Enumerable from every number with Enuerable.Repeat
3. Flatening every Enumerable to a single Enumerable

That logic above is exactly what SelectMany() does. So the solutions is

```
var nums = Unfold(10, x => x+5).Take(4).SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Repeat(x, 5));
```

Now `nums` is the following list `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25]`

Comment: Linq-ishly awesome answer.  Much like using a sledgehammer to remove a loose tooth.

Comment: Probably you could also say, this is just the "functional programming" way.

Comment: +1 Wow. I almost expected this could not be done with a Linq sequence without sacrificing readability. But your solution looks nice and very, very readable. (and nicely explained, too, btw...)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var n = 20;
var start = 10;
var step = 5;
var increment = 5;
var x = Enumerable
    .Range(0, n)
    .Select(y => (float)start + increment * (y / step))
    .ToArray();
```

Note that although I like Linq very much, I must agree with the Robert Harvey that a loop would probably be more legible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Linq probably isn't your best choice for this problem.  That being said, something like this, perhaps?

```
var groupCount = 4;
var elementsPerGroup = 5;
var increment = 5;

var a = Enumerable
    .Range(0, groupCount)
    .Select(i => Enumerable
                     .Range(0, elementsPerGroup)
                     .Select(r => (float)(10 + increment * i)).ToArray())
    .SelectMany(i => i)
    .ToArray();
```